# Next-auth how to prevent session new expiration date?

Tags: session, next.js, next-auth

I am using `next-auth` in my next app for user authentification.

Each time the user switch to another window or tab in the browser, and go back to the application, the `session` takes a new expiration date like shown below :

```js
{
  expires: '2023-01-05T00:53:50.523Z',
  accessToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzOTZiMTlhYTczMmUzMzYwMjU2ZjBlMiIsImlhdCI6MTY3Mjg3OTk3MCwiZXhwIjoxNjcyOTY2MzcwfQ.NSFAUb9kHgKkCoBtw60tG9vgOXMTwX8lD7Kgb8TxsFI'
}
```

swith tab and go back

```js
{
  expires: '2023-01-05T00:54:05.724Z',
  accessToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzOTZiMTlhYTczMmUzMzYwMjU2ZjBlMiIsImlhdCI6MTY3Mjg3OTk3MCwiZXhwIjoxNjcyOTY2MzcwfQ.NSFAUb9kHgKkCoBtw60tG9vgOXMTwX8lD7Kgb8TxsFI'
}
```

Is it possible to prevent that ? I don't want to have a new expiration date. I read the official [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options) but I found nothing about this feature.

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a `refetchOnWindowFocus` option to `false` on `SessionProvider` to avoid it auto refresh on every focus tab.

[Documentation example](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#options)

```js
<SessionProvider
  session={session}
  // In case you use a custom path and your app lives at "/cool-app" rather than at the root "/"
  basePath="cool-app"
  // Re-fetch session every 5 minutes
  refetchInterval={5 * 60}
  // Disable Re-fetches session when window is focused
  refetchOnWindowFocus={false}
>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</SessionProvider>;
```